# module within package not available after import statement

Tags: python, tensorflow

The script:

```
import tensorflow.python
tensorflow.python
```

results in `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

How can this happen?  `from tensorflow import python` works as expected, as does `from tensorflow.python import keras`.  I thought I understood the basics of the Python import mechanism but I don't understand under what circumstances `import x.y` appears to succeed but without adding `x.y` to the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`tensorflow/__init__.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/__init__.py), you will see it explicitly deletes the name `python` at the end:

```
# These symbols appear because we import the python package which
# in turn imports from tensorflow.core and tensorflow.python. They
# must come from this module. So python adds these symbols for the
# resolution to succeed.
# pylint: disable=undefined-variable
del python
del core
# pylint: enable=undefined-variable
```

For this reason, `tensorflow.python` cannot be accessed, because the attribute `python` of the module object `tensorflow` has been deleted. You can still import things from there, though:

```
from tensorflow.python import ops  # Works
```

If you want to specifically access the `tensorflow.python` module, well, you cannot through this name, but you can import it too into another name:

```
from tensorflow import python as tfpython
print(tfpython)
# <module 'tensorflow.python' from '...'>
```